# Proof verification: Munkres exercise 10, section 23

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Can someone please verify my proof or offer suggestions for improvement? I'm thoroughly confused by this question, and I'm sure there's a mistake somewhere in my proof.

> Let $\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in J}$ be an indexed family of connected spaces. Let $X$ be the product space $$\displaystyle{\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha}$$
>
> Let $a = (a_\alpha)$ be a fixed point of $X$.
>
> (a) Given any finite subset $K$ of $J$, let $X_K$ denote the subspace of $X$ consisting of all points $x = (x_\alpha)$ such that $x_\alpha = a_\alpha$ for $\alpha \notin K$. Show that $X_K$ is connected.
>
> (b) Show that the union $Y$ of the spaces $X_K$ is connected.
>
> (c) Show that $X$ equals the closure of $Y$; conclude that $X$ is connected.

(a) Let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n$ be the indices in $K$. It can easily be seen that $X_K$ is homeomorphic with $X_{\alpha_1} \times X_{\alpha_2} \times \ldots \times X_{\alpha_n}$. Since a finite product of connected spaces is connected, it follows that $X_K$ is connected.

(b) Let $X_{K_1}$ and $X_{K_2}$ be two such subspaces. We show that $X_{K_1}$ and $X_{K_2}$ belong to the same connected component. Let $x$ be any element of $X_{K_1 \cap K_2}$. It can easily be seen that $x \in X_{K_1}$ and $x \in X_{K_2}$. So, $X_{K_1} \cup X_{K_2}$ is connected, being the union of two connected spaces having a point in common. Therefore, $Y$ is connected.

(c) Let $(y_\alpha) \in \displaystyle{\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha}$. Let $U = \displaystyle{\prod_{\alpha \in J} U_\alpha}$ be a basis element containing $y$. Let $\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n\}$ be the indices for which $U_\alpha \neq X_\alpha$. If we set $L = \{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n\}$, then $X_L$ intersects $U$ (at any sequence $(z_\alpha)$ in which $y_\beta$ equals $z_\beta$ at all coordinates other than $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$). So, $X$ equals the closure of $Y$.

Comment: In b), you don't want to consider $X_{K_1\cap K_2}$, since $K_1\cap K_2$ could be empty. Instead use $a\in X_{K_1}\cap X_{k_2}$. The rest looks fine.

Comment: Actually, you need to consider arbitrary unions, but the same argument applies.

Comment: But even if $K_1 \cap K_2$ is empty, $a \in X_{K_1 \cap K_2}$.

Comment: You're right, my bad. But you still need to consider arbitrary unions, not just the union of two sets. But for this you can use the same argument.

Comment: I don't see the section 152, could you give the page where the exercise is ?

Comment: @idm My bad. It's section 23, page 152.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Since I've shown that any two elements belong to the same connected component, doesn't the statement follow for arbitrary unions?

Comment: Yes, it's true that if you have a union of connected spaces, where the pairwise intersection is non-empty, the whole union is connected. But you never say this.